# Why the div doesn't surround its children?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have an `img` and a two `p`s inside of a `div`, when I apply

```
div#column! {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

the border just appears as a single line. Why does that happen? Here's an example of it: http://jsfiddle.net/WZ8Gc/

Comment: add a overflow : hidden to it

Comment: @DarkBee, it worked. But can you explain me why it happens? And what's with the overflow?

Comment: overflow:auto would be better but it happens as you are floating your image - you need to clear the floats otherwise the containing object will collapse, setting the overflow of the object will also make it behave

Comment: The `overflow : hidden` forces the container to calculate its height based on his children. U can do it with a clear div as well, see answer

Answer (score 2):

Because you used `float` on the paragraphs, and not on the container. Here is an updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/WZ8Gc/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
    div#column_1 {
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow : hidden;            
    }
```

or :

```
<div id="column_1"> 
... content ....
   <div style="clear : both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using additional markup to clear a float is obsolete. Try a clearfix instead. http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

P `float` is problem so Use Clear fix css May be it will help you

```
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
.clearfix {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give  the height in the div#column_1 like this it show all border around your image.
 div#column_1 {                border: 1px solid red;                   height:205px;            }